# Build libjpeg-turbo as .dll

Tags: msys2, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

I am looking for parametr for build libjpeg-turbo as .dll using MSYS2.

```
cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" -DENABLE_STATIC=ON -DENABLE_SHARED=ON ...
```

I have tried all combinations of STATIC=ON/OFF and SHARED=ON/OFF but I always got `.a` or `.dll.a` files.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular library, but in general if you build as a shared library you should get a `.dll` file and also a `.dll.a` file.  Are you sure you didn't get a `.dll` generated somewhere when `ENABLED_SHARED=ON`?

Answer (score 0):

The libjpeg-turbo library is already deployed as an msys2 package which contains both the source code and the binaries.
You can install libjpeg-turbo from the msys2 shell with the following command:
`$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libjpeg-turbo`
After installation you can copy the binary files you need (*.dll, *.dll.a) to the location you prefer to link them to your project.

Answer (score 0):

The CMake command you use is not appropriate on Windows.
You are asking CMake to generate a makefile for Unix, and as you know, Unix does not use DLLs.
You should (using the mingw64 shell) move to the `build` directory and use the following command:
`$ cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DENABLE_STATIC=ON -DENABLE_SHARED=ON ..` (not "Unix Makefiles")
At this point (remaining in the `build` directory) you should type:
`mingw32-make`
Now the compilation will begin and you will find the dll and all files you need.